# System freeze/crash on Asus q407iq whenever I don't use acpi=off

Tags: linux, freeze, kubuntu, acpi, asus

I have an Asus q407iq (bios 302, the latest) that I've installed kubuntu 20.10 onto. I've tried using kernels up to 5.12.1, I've tried using earlier os versions (+ other distros), and I've lost track of how many different boot parameters I've tried and the only thing that doesn't cause freezing/crashing is acpi=off. This even happens if I boot straight to runlevel 1, where only the shell prompt is visible!

It's driving me crazy because when acpi=off, I only have access to 1 core, the battery monitor doesn't work, and most annoying of all is my touchpad completely disables.

What happens without that acpi parameter is the computer functions normally for 1-2 minutes, and then the screen appears to freeze. If I wait another tenish seconds, the screen goes completely black, and I'm unable to do anything except a hard power off. I've monitored system temps to ensure nothing is overheating, and I don't see anything obvious in any logs I've checked. I'm just completely stumped! Anyone have any ideas? Willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: I had *that* happen a whole lot with old distros like Debian 9 and such...turn out this might be caused (don't have source on this but just was a wild guess i had at the time) by the chipset/integrated graphic's driver. I noticed it mainly does this with Intel for whatever reason, but I saw it happen a lot more on older distros. Can't be sure if this is the actual reason but might be a clue I hope...

Comment: BTW, this should have been the first thing to think of, but you probably should look/copy paste the content of your `/var/log/` directory (preferably on a paste service, like pastebin, etc), so it can shed more lights on what's actually causing the freeze. (which seems to stem from a lots of possible problem beside what i mentioned in my previous comment)

Comment: Hi @NordineLotfi the Q407IQ uses an AMD Ryzen 5 4500U processor with integrated amdgpu, and also a dedicated NVIDIA GeForce MX350. Like I said, this even happens in just a shell - booting straight into runlevel 1-3 shells still have the issue as well. I can't even switch to a virtual terminal via ctrl+alt+fx. I'll post some log files shortly.

Comment: dmesg: https://pastebin.com/GVvnc6qk

syslog: https://pastebin.com/9fkR1zyG

kern: https://pastebin.com/7eav27cs

xorg: https://pastebin.com/29RWWSNv

Comment: hmm, I forgot to mention, but getting the logs I mentioned *when* you don't use `acpi=off` would be better here, so there an before/after details if possible. (you can easily get them by using a live environment and mounting the disk where `/var/log/` was iirc

Comment: Pretty sure those are without `acip=off` - from the dmesg log, you can see
`[    0.000000] kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.12.4-051204-generic root=UUID=314ce4fe-67a6-4fa4-bf19-b0f33fd15ce4 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7`
which doesn't have the `acpi=off` param. I can do a live disk tomorrow though just to be completely transparent

Comment: so, you uploaded those logs *while* not having `acpi=off` set, is that right? And I'm guessing you did this *before* it even freeze/crash (which is a certain range of time/certain timeframe that's nearly always the same?)...but to be able to diagnose this faster, I believe this would help even more if you could let it freeze/crash, *then* go into a live system and retrieve the log (which will contain the possible *reason* for this happening)

Comment: I cleared my logs, then restarted without `acpi=off`, let it crash, then I reloaded with `acpi=off`, & captured the logs. But yeah, I'll do with a live disc as not to pollute the logs with the reboot with the parameter. I also have to load the live disc with `acpi=off` too or it'll crash, but that shouldn't affect my actual system logs.

Comment: The syslog dump includes ```
May 17 20:04:10 aloha systemd[1]: Finished Network Manager Wait Online.
May 17 20:04:10 aloha systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
May 17 20:04:10 aloha systemd[1]: Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
May 17 20:04:10 aloha systemd[1]: Starting Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
....
``` So temperature appears to be a factor?